# matplotlib funcanimation return list of artist objects error: "list has no attribute set_animated"

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I have a code that generates an animation and saves it to disk. My plots have a lot of lines and texts to be animated, so rather than writing "return line1, line2, line3..." i created a list of lines and a list of texts, and i just return the lists in the init and animation functions.

Now, this works, but then i sent the code to a coworker and when he attempts to run it he gets the error: "list has no attribute set_animated"

i've put a few prints here and there to check that the list object being passed around is ok, and it seems everything is in order. We have verified by putting his pc next to mine and executing the exact same script, and he woudl get the error and i wouldn't

of course, i tried writing down "return line1, line2, line3..." in the init function. This works, but then the same type of issue arises in the animation fucntion. And beises, the whole point of using the lists was not having to write down dozens of terms in each return for each animation

i'm very confused as to why it works on my pc and it does not on his

This is my init fucntion:

```
def init():
    for l in range(0, len(line)):
        line[l].set_data([], [])

    for t in range(0, len(texta)):
        texta[t].set_text([])

    return line, texta
```

One animation function:

```
def animate1(i):
    Pot = GenPwr[:i]
    t_pot = Time[:i]
    RotSp = RotSpeed[:i]
    RotTh = RotThrust[:i]
    WindV = WindVel[:i]

    #___________GENPWR___________#
    texta[0].set_text("GenPwr (kW)=" + str(GenPwr[i]))
    line[0].set_data(t_pot, Pot)

    # ___________ROTSPEED___________#
    texta[1].set_text(
        "RotSpeed (rpm)=" + str(RotSpeed[i]),
    )
    line[1].set_data(t_pot, RotSp)

    # ___________ROTTHRUST___________#
    texta[2].set_text(
        "RotThrust (kW)=" + str(RotThrust[i]),
    )
    line[2].set_data(t_pot, RotTh)

    # ___________WINDVEL___________#
    texta[3].set_text(
        "WindVel (m/s)=" + str(round(WindVel[i], 2)),
    )
    line[3].set_data(t_pot, WindV)

    return line, texta
```

And here an example of how i assign the lsits:

```
fig, ((ax1, ax2), (ax3, ax4)) = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True)

(line1,) = ax1.plot([], [], lw=1)
(line2,) = ax2.plot([], [], lw=1, color="r")
(line3,) = ax3.plot([], [], lw=1, color="c")
(line4,) = ax4.plot([], [], lw=1, color="m")

line = [line1, line2, line3, line4]
```

Comment: Are you and your coworker using the same version of python and matplotlib?

Comment: i'm using pyhton 3.8.5 and he is using 3.9.0. I though about it but if it's me using the lower version, it should work on his machine. Regarding matplotlib i'm using 3.4.2 and he is using 3.4.3. Again i'd be the one using the older version

Comment: I updated matplotlib to 3.4.3 in a venv and i can run the code no problem